# Loading packages in custom class based on option

Tags: etoolbox, documentclass-writing

I'd like to define a custom documentclass for assignments which can be optionally passed the `minionpro` argument to use the Adobe Minion Pro font; if it's not set, the Adobe Utopia font (`fourier`) shall be used. Now, no matter what I try, pdfLaTeX always spits out the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 \DeclareOption(mi
                     nionpro){
```

Here is the **mwe.cls**:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2015/12/07 mwe.cls]

\DeclareOption(minionpro){
    % Adobe Minion Pro font for the document, Euler font for math
    \RequirePackage{MinionPro}
    \RequirePackage{eulervm}
}

\DeclareOption(utopia){
    % Adobe Utopia font for the document
    \RequirePackage{fourier}
}

\ExecuteOptions{utopia}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\endinput
```

And here the **mwe.tex**

```
\documentclass{mwe2}
\begin{Document}
content...
\end{Document}
```

Alternatively, I tried using the `etoolbox` package to work around the package loading inside of the options, but that gave me the same error. Nevertheless, here the modified **mwe.cls**:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2015/12/07 mwe.cls]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\providebool{minionpro}
\setbool{minionpro}{false}

\DeclareOption(minionpro){
    \setbool{minionpro}{true}
}


\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifthenelse{minionpro}{
    % Adobe Minion Pro font for the document, Euler font for math
    \RequirePackage{MinionPro}
    \RequirePackage{eulervm}
}{
    % Adobe Utopia font for the document
    \RequirePackage{fourier}
}

\endinput
```

Comment: `\DeclareOption` needs curly `{}` not round `()` braces and `\ifthenelse` is from `ifthen` not `etoolbox`. I think it should be something like `\ifbool`.

Comment: (Of course, the option exists to use the rock-solid expl3 API.)

Comment: Sorry, the `etoolbox`/`ifthen` mixup is due to me copying the MWE together from multiple sources, I've also tried the already-deprecated `ifthen` package prior to `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\ifthenelse` is in the `ifthen` package. If you want to check whether a boolean `bool` is true you can use the command `\ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{}{}`. Also I think that you have to declare the boolean values before using the `\newboolean` command.

Additionally as already pointed out by Nicola Talbot in the comments the `\DeclareOption` command needs curly brackets `{}` instead of `()`.

I think the following version of `mwe.cls` should work:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2015/12/07 mwe.cls]

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{minionpro}
\newboolean{utopia}


\DeclareOption{minionpro}{%
    % Adobe Minion Pro font for the document, Euler font for math
    \setboolean{minionpro}{true}}

\DeclareOption{utopia}{%
    % Adobe Utopia font for the document
    \setboolean{utopia}{true}}

\ExecuteOptions{utopia}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifthenelse{\boolean{minionpro}}{%
    \RequirePackage{MinionPro}
    \RequirePackage{eulervm}}{}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{utopia}}{%
    \RequirePackage{fourier}}{}

\endinput
```

EDIT: In the following an alternative version using `etoolbox` instead of `ifthen`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2015/12/07 mwe.cls]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{minionpro}
\newbool{utopia}

\DeclareOption{minionpro}{%
    % Adobe Minion Pro font for the document, Euler font for math
    \booltrue{minionpro}}

\DeclareOption{utopia}{%
    % Adobe Utopia font for the document
    \booltrue{utopia}}

\ExecuteOptions{utopia}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifbool{minionpro}{%
    \RequirePackage{MinionPro}
    \RequirePackage{eulervm}}{}
\ifbool{utopia}{\RequirePackage{fourier}}{}

\endinput
```